# Bottom Button Nativescript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui

I have this code

```
<ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar"></ActionBar>
<GridLayout rows="auto, *, auto">
    <ScrollView col="0" row="1">
        <StackLayout>
            <GridLayout rows="auto, auto, auto, auto, *, 60">
                <StackLayout row="0" backgroundColor="#eee" class="p-20">
                    <Label text="Send email to"></Label>
                    <Label text="email@gmail.com"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
                <Label row="1" text="subject" class="p-10"></Label>
                <TextField row="2" hint="Enter text... "></TextField>
                <FlexboxLayout row="3" colSpan="2" justifyContent="space-between" class="p-10">
                    <Label text="message" class="label-title"></Label>
                    <Label class="label-title">
                        <FormattedString>
                            <Span text="20" padding="90"></Span>
                            <Span text="/"></Span>
                            <Span text="300"></Span>
                        </FormattedString>
                    </Label>
                </FlexboxLayout>
                <TextView row="4" text="" hint="Enter your message..."></TextView>
            </GridLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <GridLayout row="2">
        <Button text="send" class="btn-message"></Button>
    </GridLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

and on playground works like expected: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=2oSzob

but on my device doesn't, the bottom button is hidden below the keyboard. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Have you included the `nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager` plugin in your project?

Answer (score 1):

`nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager` should work for iOS.

For Android make sure `windowSoftInputMode` is set to `adjustResize` in `App_Resources/Android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">
```